# ArrayList indexOf

Tags: java, arraylist, indexof

I just started learning about the ArrayList class in Java. I have the following code below testing out the ArrayList class and it's methods:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class NewArrayList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();

        String s = new String();
        myList.add(s);
        String b = new String();
        myList.add(b);

        int theSize = myList.size();
        System.out.println("ArrayList size: " + theSize);

        boolean isTrue = myList.contains(s);
        System.out.println(isTrue);

        int whereIsIt = myList.indexOf(s);
        System.out.println(whereIsIt);
        int whereIsIt2 = myList.indexOf(b);
        System.out.println(whereIsIt2);

    }

}
```

The `indexOf` method shows whats the index of an object. So since I added two objects, `s` and `b` to the `myList` ArrayList object reference, it should have 2 objects inside the index. The output of `whereIsit` and `whereIsit2` is both `0`. Shouldn't it be `0 1`??

Answer (score 10):

You're adding two `String` objects with the same value (empty string) to the list.

So your list looks like

```
["", ""]
```

You're then invoking the equivalent of `indexOf("")`, where `indexOf(..)` uses the `Object#equals(Object)` method to compare objects. The first element in the list is equal to `""`, so that index is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Please read method description in the docs before using  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/ArrayList.html

```
int     indexOf(Object o)
Returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in this list, or -1   if    this list does not contain the element.
```

and

```
public int lastIndexOf(Object o)

Returns the index of the last occurrence of the specified element in this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element. More formally, returns the highest index i such that (o==null ? get(i)==null : o.equals(get(i))), or -1 if there is no such index.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you just create two objects and that has no value so it will be treated as empty string. So the Indexof will returns the first occurence of the given object.

If you assign different values to s and b then result what you are expecting that will get. Please try with below code.

```
    String s = "String1";
    myList.add(s);
    String b = "String2";
    myList.add(b);

    int whereIsIt = myList.indexOf(s);
    System.out.println(whereIsIt);
    int whereIsIt2 = myList.indexOf(b);
    System.out.println(whereIsIt2);
```